# Multiple implementations of CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I'm wondering if it's problematic to implement two different SDK's that use CLLocationManager functionality in one app.

Both SDK's are monitoring CLBeaconRegions, and both have implemented different classes with CLLocationManager instances and delegate implementations.

Possible problems:

What if one of the SDK's removes all monitored CLBeaconRegions from it's CLLocationManager. Does that  influence the other SDK's CLLocationManager as well?

What if both SDK's start looking for the same UUID (but with a different CLBeaconRegion identifier)... do both get a delegate call?

I can't think of any other reason why this shouldn't work, but maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with Shared Instance ?
What you can do is try to manage your code with same location manager instance.
So any change in delegate may reflect in single class from there you can manage you code .

Example :- 
.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface LocationManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) CLLocationManager         *objLocationManager;
@property (nonatomic,assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D    currentcoordinate;
+ (LocationManager *) SharedInstance;
+ (CLLocation *)      currentLocation;
@end
```

.m

```
#define currentCordinates [LocationManager SharedInstance].currentcoordinate
#define currentLocationmanger   [LocationManager SharedInstance].objLocationManager
// Shared Manager
static LocationManager *SharedInstance = nil;

+ (LocationManager *) SharedInstance
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (SharedInstance == nil)
        {
            SharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
            currentLocationmanger = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
            currentLocationmanger.delegate = [LocationManager SharedInstance];


            /* Pinpoint our location with the following accuracy:
             *
             *     kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation  highest + sensor data
             *     kCLLocationAccuracyBest               highest
             *     kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters   10 meters
             *     kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters      100 meters
             *     kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer          1000 meters
             *     kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers    3000 meters
             */
            currentLocationmanger.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;

            /* Notify changes when device has moved x meters.
             * Default value is kCLDistanceFilterNone: all movements are reported.
             */
            currentLocationmanger.distanceFilter = 2.0f;

            /* Notify heading changes when heading is > 5.
             * Default value is kCLHeadingFilterNone: all movements are reported.
             */
            currentLocationmanger.headingFilter = 5;

            [LocationManager SharedInstance].geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

            [[LocationManager SharedInstance].objLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

            // update location
            if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
                [currentLocationmanger startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
            }
        }
    }
    return SharedInstance;
}
```

//other delgates and stuff to manage in .m

Some where in when you use is use with shared intace

```
//region.span = span;
    region.center = [LocationManager SharedInstance].currentcoordinate;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get this principle, but it's not really relevant right now, because I can't apply this since I use two third party SDK's...

Comment: Which sdk you have used?

Comment: Two SDK's from iBeacon companies (not from iBeacon manufacturers)